# How to access HttpServletRequest inside Spring component class

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to access httpServletRequest inside a component class. I tried it in several ways.

```
@Component
public class MyService{

 @Resource
 WebServiceContext wsCtxt;

 public void myWebMethod(){
  MessageContext msgCtxt = wsCtxt.getMessageContext();
  HttpServletRequest req = ( 
  (HttpServletRequest)msgCtxt.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
  String clientIP = req.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

This didn't work for me. because WebServiceContext is always null. Then I tried same code inside Web service class. Then that code is working. My Requirement it to get HttpServletRequest inside component class. (ultimately What i am trying to do it get client host from request header). 
It this possible to do ?. Are there any alternatives for this ?

Comment: Just curious to know why you want to do that?

Comment: we are having a different environment such as test, dev, production. Current implementation of our project is to get default host as a localhost. but we can override host from vm options. like **-Dserver_url=test.xxx.com** ,   then web service will call other web services in test environment.  Now we are going to get host from header which is sent through nginx.

Answer (score 2):

### **Method #1**

Have you tried passing the request object into your component by passing it in as an argument to your service method, and from your service to your component method?

```
// in your controller... Spring provides the request object
public String myController(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
    //...
    myService.myServiceMethod(request,...);
}

// in your service...
public void myServiceMethod(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
    //...
    myComponent.myWebMethod(request,...);
}

// in your component
public String myWebMethod(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {

    // use the raw request object
}
```

### **Method #2**

Also, `DispatcherServlet` exposes the request object by wrapping it in a `ServletRequestAttributes` object, which in turn is stored in a `ThreadLocal` variable. The actual storing takes place in `RequestContextHolder` and its static methods. You can access it as follows:

```
public void myWebMethod(){
    //...

    RequestAttributes reqAttr = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    ServletRequestAttributes servlReqAttr = (ServletRequestAttributes)reqAttr;
    HttpServletRequest req = servlReqAttr.getRequest();

    //...

}
```

Although a little verbose, you can see what's going on.

You could also condense it:

```
((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

I hope this helps!