# Method arguments in http put request (csv? Body with String?)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csv, http

I am trying to write a method that will respond to this http request. Unfortunately, I do not know what the argument of such a method should be.

```
cat data.csv | curl --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --request PUT --data-binary @- http://localhost:8080/endpoint
```

Swagger :

```
put:
  tags:
  - "employees"
  summary: "Stores employees hierarchy tree on server"
  description: "Sends or replaces employees hierarchy tree on server"
  operationId: "endpoint"
  consumes:
  - "text/plain"
  parameters:
  - in: "body"
    name: "body"
    description: "CSV with four columns - employee id, employee name, employee surname and employee superior id. Columns are separated with ',' character."
    required: true
    schema:
      type: string
      example:[tons of employees data here]
```

At first I thought it would be a Multipartfile and then I would just process it (see dummy approach below), but then I saw a "string" in swagger and it confused me a bit. I have no clue anymore what the format of the input data is.

```
 @PutMapping("/endpoint")
public void readCSV(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    String content = new String(file.getBytes());
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same thing right now. Actually, you have the information that it is String, text / plain (Swagger) and Content-Type "text / plain" which makes me believe that the transmitted data is just a String that was created from the data contained in the CSV file. So your method may look like this

```
@PutMapping("/endpoint")
public void readCSV(@RequestBody String csvData)
```

and this csvData String will contain all the text from the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Or you can access the HttpRequest directly and read the request body from `HttpServletRequest`
[How to access HttpServletRequest inside Spring component class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868713/how-to-access-httpservletrequest-inside-spring-component-class/50878414)

Multipart is possible as well, but then you can't use text/plain and you will also have to format your body according to the Multipart format.

Comment: I cannot edit the request. I have to conform to it. The whole problem is with this part:  
`@PutMapping("/endpoint")
    public void readCSV( > WHAT ARGUMENT SHOULD BE HERE < )  {
}`
I will try with HttpServletRequest and retrieving data from Collections